# Managing roles on the database

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 5, I have some difficulties to manage roles with the database. My goal is to finally get the corresponding role by asking

I've got a `Profil` entity linked to the database with some boolean fields that defined to specific access:

```
$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

And also, define a hierarchy as explained in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#hierarchical-roles).

Below is my `Profil` entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProfilRepository")
 * 
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name", message="A profil with this name already exist.")
 */
class Profil
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $editMetadatas;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $editVisas;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isAdmin;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEditMetadatas(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->editMetadatas;
    }

    public function setEditMetadatas(bool $editMetadatas): self
    {
        $this->editMetadatas = $editMetadatas;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsAdmin(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isAdmin;
    }

    public function setIsAdmin(bool $isAdmin): self
    {
        $this->isAdmin = $isAdmin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

The `Profil` entity is linked to a `User` entity through a classical ManyToOne relation.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use App\Entity\Profil;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5, columnDefinition="ENUM('en_GB', 'fr_FR')", options={"default": "fr_FR"})
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default": false})
     */
    private $activated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $lastConnected;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Profil", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $profil;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $company;

    private $roles = [];

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }


    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocale(): ?string
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    public function setLocale(string $locale): self
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getActivated(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->activated;
    }

    public function setActivated(bool $activated): self
    {
        $this->activated = $activated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastConnected(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->lastConnected;
    }

    public function setLastConnected(\DateTimeInterface $lastConnected): self
    {
        $this->lastConnected = $lastConnected;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfil(): ?profil
    {
        return $this->profil;
    }

    public function setProfil(?profil $profil): self
    {
        $this->profil = $profil;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        if (empty($roles))
        {
            $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];
            if ($profil->getProfil()->getEditMetadatas()) array_push($roles, 'ROLE_METADATAS');
        }
        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Regarding the method `getRoles()`, I think I'm not doing right because I'm not able to fetch to data on the `getRoles()` function on loading. The `getProfil` loaded during logging method send back an empty array because it has not been loaded yet.

I think this is a pretty common feature: how should I suppose load the `Profil` datas?

Comment: well, in theory your `getProfil` method should work. what definitely shouldn't work is running `foreach` on that object, or at least the meaning is ... questionable. However: roles are a tricky thing in symfony (when used in isGranted), because they are attached to the *session* and are not refreshed when the user changes. maybe that's already one reason?

Comment: Dear Jakumi,

You're right regarding the `foreach` statement. It was a mistake. I've corrected the code below, the question is still open as I'm not able the get the `profil` array filled during the first execution of `getProfil()` method.

Comment: does your `dump` produce anything? because it should. the line after that though is crap, because `$profil` is undefined at that point. you could try eager-loading the profil.

Comment: The dump produce an empty array. By the way, I found a solution I will post. Not sure it is the more conventional way.

Comment: it just rubs me the wrong way, why can `dump($this->getProfil())` produce an array? it either is `null` or a `Profil` that's how it is defined. it can't produce an array. ever. or did you talk about a different dump? Sadly, you edited your post so the original code is gone.

Comment: Dear Jakumi. Apologies for the mistake, I meant an empty entity (not array). But today, I was not able to reproduce the problem. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, not sure it is the best one.

```
public function getRoles(): array
{ 
    if (empty($this->roles)) {
        if ($this->getProfil()->getEditMetadatas()) $this->roles[] = 'ROLE_METADATAS';
    }
    $this->roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    return array_unique($this->roles);
}
```

The property `roles` is defined the first time. The property `getProfil` is able to get the `Profil` object correctly filled. This is pretty surprising because I don't see why I get an empty array with the previous code. Whatever, it is working.